# VS Code's git extension shows wrong pre-commit hook failure

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code 1.81 with the built-in git extension and a set of pre-commit hooks with pre-commit 1.16.1.

The pre-commit config looks as follows:

```
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        name: isort
        entry: isort
        language: python
        types: [python]
        additional_dependencies: ['isort']
        args: [--profile, black]
      - id: black
        name: black
        entry: black
        language: python
        types: [python]
        additional_dependencies: ['black==20.8b0', 'click==8.0.4']
      - id: flake8
        name: flake8
        entry: flake8
        language: python
        types: [python]
        additional_dependencies: ['flake8==3.8.4']
        args: [--config, .flake8]
```

The issue I have is that if one of the hooks fails, VS Code just produces a pop-up message that mentions `isort` - presumably because it's at the top of the list - and not the actual hook that fails.

For example, if `flake8` finds an issue, but assuming there are no issues identified by `isort` and `black`, VS Code shows this on commit:

[image: VS Code error]

I can only figure out what actually is happening by going to Output and then Git and get the full message - which indeed says that it is `flake8` failing.

Would anyone know how to solve this? I want VS Code to show me the hook that is actually failing without having to go to Output.

Comment: off topic but your flake8 and black configurations are fork bombs

Comment: vs code only shows the first line -- there isn't an option to show more afaik

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "fork bombs"? :-)

Comment: it's a common term -- I'll let you search it yourself

Comment: I see. Any tips on how to fix?

Comment: the official configs don't have this issue -- you're using the "at-your-own-support" `repo: local` escape hatch

Comment: Yes, I need to use `local` due to my company's IT setup.

Comment: find what's different between them and make it not different and that'll fix it for ya

Comment: `require_serial`? :-)

Comment: Good point on Show Command Output - that's definitely a good improvement. Want to maybe post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments by the asker, posting this as an answer:

> I can only figure out what actually is happening by going to Output and then Git and get the full message

Right beside the button to open the log, there is "Show Command Output", which should open a temporary file that shows the output on its own. see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/95354/files. It may not solve exactly the problem you asked for, but it's an improvement over scrolling through the Output Panel.

If you want VS Code to be changed, I'd suggest that you [open an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose) asking for the change to be made.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.